# Trying to connect to Quickbooks Online using consolibyte/quickbooks-php

Tags: php, quickbooks

I have cloned the repository, set up my web server using IIS and NGrok, and I have updated the config file with the keys from my Intuit app.  I have added the three links in the redirect URI.  The index page loads just fine, but when I click the "connect to quickbooks" button, I get an error telling me "Could not build an authorization URL.Oh no, something bad happened: :".

I feel like I am missing something really trivial because everything seems to load and run like it should up until it tries to call the oauth.php and it does not ask for me to log into quickbooks to complete this step.  It tries to load the oauth.php and fails on connecting to $the_tenant.

```
// For OAuth2 (all new application, and what you should be migrating to)
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config_oauthv2.php';

// For old/legacy applications
//require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/config_oauthv1.php';

// Try to handle the OAuth request
if ($IntuitAnywhere->handle($the_tenant))
{
    ; // The user has been connected, and will be redirected to $that_url 
automatically.
}
else
{
// If this happens, something went wrong with the OAuth handshake
die('Oh no, something bad happened: ' . $IntuitAnywhere->errorNumber()    
    $IntuitAnywhere->errorMessage());
}
```

I had expected being able to log into quickbooks and start doing some example queries but I am stuck at the step right before this.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/b5BhwvG is a picture of what I am seeing via chrome when I try to connect to quickbooks.

Comment: How are things configured in your app on developer.intuit.com? How are things configured in the config.php file? Did you make sure to enter in your client ID and client secret? I think we'd need to see the rest of your sandbox settings (you can mask the client ID/secret if you want) to be able to help you. My bet would be you didn't configure a URL or something correctly.

Comment: I have attached two pictures. One is showing my sandbox app setup with keys/secret and redirect URI setup.  The other is the config_oauthv2.php setup. https://imgur.com/a/I7HW6Pe  https://imgur.com/a/EZ9XbnE My app is configured as a Quickbooks Online OAuth2.0 when I look under the apps dashboard.

Comment: Do you have the PHP cURL extension? Is it able to fetch httpS:// websites without turning off host/peer verification? https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/QuickBooks/IPP/IntuitAnywhere.php#L528 https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/QuickBooks/IPP/IntuitAnywhere.php#L556